# Rails4+Devise: "hide" routes when user is not authenticated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I am trying to make my admin back-office pages "invisible" for non authenticated users. Meaning when a user goes to something like `/admin/my_controller` I want to display a 404 custom page, makes him believe this is just a regular 404. And off course when the user is authenticated he will correctly access the controller.

So I got almost everything working, I'm just missing the devise/warden part. I correctly configured 404 error rescue in my Rails app (which is implemented in a controller I named `ErrorsController`), so when someone goes to a non existing uri such as `/nothing_here`, my custom 404 page correctly display.

I am trying to use `ErrorsController` as `failure_app` which is almost fully working, except that I receive an exception if I log-in with incorrect credential. I am certainly just missing one last detail. Exception is

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /unauthenticated 
The action 'create' could not be found for ErrorsController
```

Obviously the `create` action is supposed to be called from the `SessionController` not from the `ErrorsController`. And this is the last bit that is missing. How to achieve this?

---

### Custom 404 configuration

In config/application.rb

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

In config/routes.rb

```
get '*dummy', to: 'errors#index'
```

app/controllers/errors_controller.rb

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    display_404
  end
end
```

### Devise configuration

In config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = ErrorsController
end
```

### Result

- Accessing a "admin" uri without being authenticated displayed correctly display my custom 404 page
- Logging-in with devise with correct credential works as expected
- Logging-in with incorrect credential raises `AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /unauthenticated The action 'create' could not be found for ErrorsController`

Comment: Might be worth adding a create action in your errors controller that also contains a `display_404`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What for? The create action is supposed to be in the `SessionController`. My `ErrorController` is no inheriting from devise

Comment: That indeed doesn't happen and it appears that devise redirects to your `ErrorController`. Which is undesirable since it doesn't give your user an authentication error but a 404. Why do you want to catch errors in devise this way?

Comment: The only thing I try to achieve is when a non authenticated user goes to a url protected by `authenticate_user!` he will see a 404 instead of being redirected to the sign-in page

Comment: What I did on an application to achieve that was create a `before_method` with an unless statement. if the user or admin was not signed in it would show the rails 404 page by executing `raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')`.

Comment: Right, I thought about that and than I forgot :) Sound like the best way. Mind to write a quick answer so I can accept it? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more graceful way of handling errors when a user is not signed in is adding a method to your application controller. For example `display_404`
In your `display_404` method add

```
raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
```

When this method is called it will raise Rails' own error page and log 'Not Found' in the log file. In development this will be shown but on screen but for production it will only be found in the log file, so adding something like `'User was not signed in'` is a possibility.

Then using

```
before_action do
  unless admin_signed_in?
    display_404
   end
end
```

the error page will be shown when the visitor is not signed in.